# How to prevent \Gls (glossaries) from sentence-casing "3d" to "3D"?

Tags: glossaries

It seems `\Gls`, which is sentence-cases the argument, believes that "3d" sentence-cased is "3D".

If I use `\gls{3d}` at the start of the sentence, then the output will be wrong ("three" instead of "Three") if it's the first mention. If I use `\Gls{3d}`, then the output will be wrong if it isn't the first mention (`\textsc{3D}` instead of `\textsc{3d}`).

How can I fix this without manually checking where the first mention is?

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\newacronym{3d}{\textsc{3d}}{three-dimensional}
\newacronym{jae}{\textsc{jae}}{just another example}
\begin{document}
\Gls{3d} in sentence-case.

\Gls{3d} in sentence-case.

\gls{3d} in normal case.

\Gls{jae} in sentence-case.

\Gls{jae} in sentence-case.

\gls{jae} in normal case.
\end{document}
```